# Reference to this rule $I = (ab) + J$, then $I = ((a) + J) \cap ((b) + J)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, monomial-ideals

Could someone show the reference of this rule:  if $I = (ab) + J$, then $I = ((a) + J) \cap ((b) + J)$.

I have found it [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/628583/primary-decomposition-of-a-monomial-ideal).

Comment: Not quite true. In $\Bbb Z$ take $J=(0)$ and $a=6$, $b=10$. Then $((a)+J)\cap((b)+J)=(30)\ne(60)$. You need $a$ and $b$ to be coprime.

Comment: I will use it for $I=(xy,xz,yz)$ in $\Bbb R[x,y,z]$ and I believe it will be true (correct me if I am wrong), but I need the reference (the book that containing this rule).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that $I,J$ are monomial ideals, and $a,b$ monomials.

As it is already remarked [there](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/628583/primary-decomposition-of-a-monomial-ideal) in the comments, the equality holds when $a,b$ are coprime. Since you only ask for a reference (although the proof is easy enough), I'd recommend you the book of Herzog and Hibi, *Monomial Ideals*, proof of theorem 1.3.1, page 8.