# Calculate the radical of ideals

Tags: commutative-algebra

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field and consider $A=k[x,y,z]$. I am supposed to calculate $\text{rad}(x,y)= \{ f \in k[x,y,z] : f^n \in (x,y)$ $\text{for some n} \}$, $\text{rad}(x,z)$ and $\text{rad}(y,z,x^2)$.  I feel I have done something wrong, I want to check if my arguments are ok.

For $\text{rad}(x,y)$, suppose that $f \notin (x,y)$ then I can write $f=g_1(x,y)+ g_2(z)$, that is, its not only a function of $x$ and $y$ but also contains a constant term or a term which is a function of $z$, however then we will never have $f^n \in (x,y)$ because $f^n$ always contains $g_{2}^n(z)$. So that $\text{rad}(x,y) = (x,y)$

With the same argument I have calculated $\text{rad}(x,z)=(x,z)$ and $\text{rad}(z,y,x^2)=(x,y,z)$. Is this correct?

Comment: A good thing to know is that prime ideals are their own radical, which often helps with checking in these sort of problems.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft I see, and $(x,y)$ and $(x,z)$ are prime ideals?

Comment: Yes (just consider the quotient by them to see this).

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft, thanks. Was my calculation for $(z,y,x^2)$ wrong?

Comment: No, your calculation was correct.

Comment: Related to http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1095586/find-shortest-primary-decomposition.

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:* (1). A prime ideal is always equal to it's own radical.

(2). For $I = (y, z, x^2),$ you can consider the ring $A/I.$ Then the nilradical of this ring will be the radical of $I$ in $A.$ Now $A/I \cong k[x]/x^2.$ What is the nilradical in this ring?

Comment: Alternatively for the second one, he has already found a prime ideal contained in the radical.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft: yes!! OP already found $\text{rad}(y, z, x^2).$ I just gave an alternate way to this.